# pandas adding columns to bottom of column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]])` that looks like

```
    0   1   2
0   1   3   5
1   2   4   6
```

I am trying to move each of the columns to the bottom of the first column. It should look something like...

```
    0
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
```

Looking for a way to do this with n rows on a much larger dataframe. I was looking for other ways with pandas `stack()` but have not found a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) and stack:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]])
res = df.T.stack()
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0  0    1
   1    2
1  0    3
   1    4
2  0    5
   1    6
dtype: int64
```

If you want to remove the index, use [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) (as suggested by @JoeFerndz):

```
res = df.T.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
dtype: int64
```

As an alternative, just [flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) the numpy array directly:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(df.values.flatten('F'))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  6
```

The `F` means:

> to flatten in column-major (Fortran- style) order.

Comment: I prefere `res = df.stack(level=0)`.

Comment: I think OP may want to add `reset_index(drop=True)`.  The desired output recommends it. So the solution will be `df.stack(level=0).reset_index(drop=True)` or `df.T.stack().reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: I'm using pandas 1.1.4 and `df.stack(level=0)` does not gives the intended output, I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using [Numpy's reshape method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html). The code below first converts the DataFrame to a Numpy array and then reshapes it to a column array by traversing the elements in Fortran-like index order. The result is finally converted back to a Pandas DataFrame.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape((-1, 1), order="F"))
```